# c++11 thread not ending in SDL

Tags: c++, multithreading, sdl-2

I have two thread which Displays the color changing SDL window.It compiles and runs fine, But I cant close them by clicking the close button of the window.

here is my code:-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

void th(string name,int x,int y,int w,int h,Uint32 flags)
{
    int i=0,o=0,p=0;
    SDL_Window *win;
    SDL_Event e;

    win = SDL_CreateWindow(name.c_str(),x,y,w,h,flags);
    SDL_ShowWindow(win);
    SDL_Surface *win_sur = SDL_GetWindowSurface(win);

    SDL_FillRect(win_sur,0,SDL_MapRGB(win_sur->format,i,o,p));
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(win);

    while(1)
    {
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
        {
            if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                goto end;
        }
        SDL_FillRect(win_sur,0,SDL_MapRGB(win_sur->format,i,o,p));
        SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(win);
        i++;o+=2;p+=3;

        SDL_Delay(10);
    }
    end:
    SDL_DestroyWindow(win);
}

int main()
{
    int lk =0;
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);
    thread t1(th,"win1",90,100,500,500,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    thread t2(th,"win2",10,400,500,500,SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    SDL_Quit();
}
```

I am using gcc 7.3 and Linux

Comment: There is a data race: both threads will try to read and write `e` global variable without sync. Same with other variables. And you never call `SDL_DestroyWindow` to get rid of windows.

Comment: @VTT I had eddited the code and still won't work.

Comment: Also you should probably handle `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the docs](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent):

> you can only call this function in the thread that set the video mode

In your case, since you call `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` in the main thread, you can only call `SDL_PollEvent` there as well. It probably never returns anything in your other threads.

Also, `SDL_QUIT` is generated when the user clicks on the close button of the *last* existing window. Check out `SDL_WINDOWEVENT_CLOSE` when you have multiple windows (or even by default, it's probably the better choice anyway).

Comment: I am calling `SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO)` from` th` thread too.  but nothing is happening.

Comment: Well unless I'm blind, that's not shown in your question. I doubt that you can call `SDL_Init` twice (or rather, that it would make any sense). And even if you were to use `SDL_InitSubSystem`, I'm pretty sure you can only have one event queue, so what you want to do wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry I had edited it on my machine.Thanks for help ☺ 